# How to Populate a Dropdownlist in VB.NET or C# From an xml with two different values while joining them using a delimiter

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, vb.net

Here is the XML. I want to populate a dropdown that  contains both the first name and the last name while separating them by the use of a comma eg TERRY,KING. I have been able to populate them separately but that is not my goal.

**XML :**

```
<row F_Name="TERRY" L_Name="King" />
<row F_Name="TOM" L_Name="LAWRENCE" />
```

**VB :**

```
    Dim strArr() As String
    Dim strArr1() As String
    strArr = names.ToString.Split("|")
    strArr1 = names.ToString.Split("|")
    DropDownList2.Items.Insert(0, New ListItem("--Select--", "0"))
    For count = 0 To strArr.Length - 1    'loop to dispay the dropdown'
        DropDownList2.Items.Add(strArr(count))
        DropDownList1.Items.Add(strArr1(count))    'L_Name dropdown'
  Next
```

Comment: this is not very clear do you mean you want to take TERRY from one file and KING from another file and join then and after they are joined add them to the drop down list?

Comment: DropdownList.Items.add(StrArr(count) & "," & strarr1(count))

Comment: you are 9 seconds faster than me

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To do this just concatenate the strings together.

```
DropDownList.Items.Add(strArr(count) & "," & strArr1(count))
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: you took sparksword's comment and made it an answer - not cool.

Comment: @DanAndrews 2 things... 1: I was waiting for clarification from the op... I have lost out on multiple answers because of waiting in the past because someone else took my idea and just made an answer off of it... 2:He chose to answer something in a comment... you do not get any credit for that... I was tired of losing answers because of people assuming things so I decided instead of waiting for an answer to my question I would just answer it and be done...

Comment: I agree that he shouldn't have answered in a comment.  With such a simple answer, I would have been tempted too.

Comment: @DanAndrews I was not sure if that was what he was looking for and we move on I guess... I will be more conscious of this in the future...